# What am I missing in this proof regarding $p(STS^{-1})=Sp(T)S^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, solution-verification

Definition: For a polynomial $p(z)=a_0+a_1z+\dots+a_nz^n$ and a linear map $T\in L(V, V)$. The polynomial $p(T)=a_0I+a_1T+\dots +a_nT^n$.

I was attempting the following exercise and am stuck on the last step.

Exercise: Suppose that $S\in L(V, V)$ is invertible. Let $p\in P(F)$ and $T\in L(V, V)$. Prove that $p(STS^{-1})=Sp(T)S^{-1}$.

Here is what I had in mind when attempting it. It's not that difficult of an exercise but I am stuck on the last step.

Proof: Consider the polynomial $p(STS^{-1})=a_0I+a_1(STS^{-1})+\dots+a_n(STS^{-1})^n$. The $n^{th}$ power of $(STS^{-1})$ can be factored as follows. $$(STS^{-1})^n=(STS^{-1})\cdots (STS^{-1})$$ $$=(ST)(S^{-1}S)(TS)\cdots(S^{-1}S)(TS^{-1})$$ $$=ST^nS^{-1}$$

Because scalar multiplication is commutative, we have that $p(STS^{-1})=a_0I+Sa_1TS^{-1}+\dots+Sa_nT^nS^{-1}$.

Now this is where I am stuck. The above can be factored to get $p(STS^{-1})=a_0I+S(a_1T+\dots+a_nT^n)S^{-1}$. But the question asks to prove that $p(STS^{-1})=S(a_0I+a_1T+\dots_+a_nT^n)S^{-1}$.

My question is: How do I bring the $a_0I$ in inside to get $Sp(T)S^{-1}$? I don't know what am I missing but I feel like there is a simple solution to this. Could someone help me with what am I missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just note the following hint: $I = SS^{-1}$.

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't think about that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Then the equation would just become $a_0SIS^{-1}$. Which can be factored as $Sa_0IS^{-1}$.

Comment: Yeah, that's right

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $Sa_2T^{2}S^{-1}=a_2(STS^{-1})(STS^{-1})=a_2(STS^{-1})^{2}$ etc. (where I have used $S^{-1}S=I$ in the first step).  In general $Sa_kT^{k}S^{-1}=a_k(STS^{-1})^{k}$.